# Looking for help creating a unique ID and making sure it doesn't exist in the DB

Tags: php, mysql, function, compare

I'm trying to create a function that, when run, creates numerical ID, checks to see if that ID exists in the DB and if it does exists then create another ID and check again until it has a unique ID. I'm stuck on how to loop in the functions withing a function

```
function createUniqueID() {

function buildUnique() {
    $uniqueID = rand(100000000000,999999999999);
    return $uniqueID;
}

function compareWithDB($uniqueID) {
    $s = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE id='{$uniqueID}'";
    $r = mysql_query($s);
    return $r;
}

function countDBRows($r) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($r) >0){
        $f = false; // found   
    } else{
        $f = true;
    }
}

$uniqueID = buildUnique();
$r = compareWithDB($uniqueID);
$f = countDBRows($r);

if (!$f) {
    $uniqueID = 'nope';
}

return $uniqueID;

}
```

Comment: Exactly -- and this way to proceed is not atomic either. Just try and insert repeatedly as long as the error is "unique constraint violation", you will succeed eventually and _this_ way is atomic.

Comment: the ID i am creating must be numbers and I dont want it to auto increment to prevent people from guessing new values. It is also something that will be part of a URL

Comment: What about something like an (AUTO_INCREMENT number + a timestamp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're much better off to call MySQL's [`UUID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) function, and store & return the value of that, unless the value absolutely must be numeric.

```
SELECT UUID();
```

Comment: but that's no solving my issue. I need the 10-12 digits as the variable. UUID creates a string letters as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a unique number, then just use [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/example-auto-increment.html)

If you want a unique *random* number (why?) create a unique index on the ID column and keep trying until you get *no* errors. This is better for concurrency: multiple concurrent calls can have the same number and pass the test. Better still, let the DB engine do it with RAND...

Comment: Using a random number actually makes a lot of sense: it is much faster at insertion time than using an auto-incremented counter (or sequence with Oracle, or whatever mechanism the RDBMS offers).

Comment: @fge: In some cases maybe, but for SQL Server/Sybase it's poison for a clustered index. Not sure if the same issue affects InnoDB so much but looks like it does  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/05/01/learning-about-mysql-table-fragmentation/ and http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PqZ6QytCemcC&pg=PT127&lpg=PT127&dq=mysql+logical+fragmentation&source=bl&ots=qufcQvdL-l&sig=euFtjXFFVHVSuMTY6vbL3m8cRYc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LpsJT_fgDsPm4QTp7_SSCA&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=mysql%20logical%20fragmentation&f=false

Comment: the ID i am creating must be numbers and I dont want it to auto increment to prevent people from guessing new values. It is also something that will be part of a URL

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest the much easier and more efficient `uniqid` function which will do this for you. It generates guaranteed unique IDs based on the timestamp in milliseconds. The generated Id is 13 digits long unless you decide to add a prefix or use extra 'entropy' (more uniqueness).

Edit: Note that this is both numbers and letters returned by the function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

**Edit 2**:
Using your method here is how to nest the loops...

```
while (true) {
    $uniqueID = buildUnique();
    $r = compareWithDB($uniqueID)
    if (countDBRows($r)) { break; }
}
```

Your unique ID is then stored in $uniqueID. I do however discourage this because it's bulky and inefficient... but there you go! :)

Comment: Yes and what happens when this uniqid randomly creates a number that exist already? Unlikely I agree but still possible.

Answer (score 1):

Theres another way too,
You can use the sha1() function in conjuction with an static variable as shown:

```
function GetUniqueID() {
    static $salt=1;
    $id = sha1("somestring".(string)$salt);
    $salt++;
    return $id;
}
```

Here  $salt being an static one retains its value between all calls incrementing ensuring unique ID's (hash of SHA1).for more security "somestring" can be made randomized also .

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question because I have found a solution of creating a big number that (likely) will never duplicate. I use three random 2-digit variables and three different date syntax.

Putting them together makes it clear that they will never duplicate unless someone happens to post during the same year, week and with the same number of seconds in the minute an also have 3 different random number all be the same.

I think the chances of this happening would be in the millions and if there are millions of posts happening then i'm sure I will have more resources to solve this issue.

```
$rand1 = rand(10,99);
$rand2 = rand(10,99);
$rand3 = rand(10,99);
$date1 = date("s"); // seconds
$date2 = date("y"); // 2 digit year
$date3 = date("W"); // week number (out of 52)
$uniqueID = $date1.$rand1.$date2.$rand2.$date3.$rand3;
return $uniqueID;
```